# updating 2 objects with each other as subobjects - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two objects, childPost and parentPost. I want to store the childPost as Subelement to parentPost and the other way around, but no matter what I try I always run into:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

There are many threads on this topic already on stackoverflow, but none seem to have the exact problem I'm having.

My code  (left out unnecessary code like error handling):

```
async.parallel([
  function () {
      originalPost.subPosts.push(post);
      originalPost.save(function (err) {
      });
  },
  function () {
      post.originalPost.push(originalPost);
      post.save(function (err, post) {
      });
  }
], sendResponse(res, 201, post));
```

What I tried beside the above solution:

- same code without `async` lib
- `setImmediate()`, `nextTick()`, `setTimeout()`
- left out the `post.originalPost.push(originalPost);` - this works, but ofc it doesn't save the sub element in my childpost

I use:

- node.js v0.11.14-pre
- mongoose
- express
- mongodb v2.4.9

**edit:** my data model:

```
var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    sharedPosts: [subPostSchema],
    originalPost: [subPostSchema],
    // ...-
});
```

my `subPostSchema` looks just like my `postSchema` (unfortunately I couldn't do a `sharedPosts: [postSchema]` without getting an error -> so I copied my Schema. Seems wrong to me, but was the only way I could get it working so far)

Comment: The error presumably comes from code serializing the structure and not knowing how to deal with circular relationships. How are you serializing the data?

Comment: Related, this may or may not be a duplicate of it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413864/are-circular-object-references-possible-in-mongodb

Comment: thanks for the post, but I think that's not exactly my problem - if I'm right ;) - because I dont have a ref to the other object but add the complete post as a `sharedPost` or an `originalPost` to the current post object

Comment: You definitely have the same problem (circular references). You'll have to sort it out in the application layer, using some kind of indirect reference (an ID or similar), rather than object references.

Comment: thank you for your help! now I get it why I had the problem. Deleting the `sharedPosts: [subPostSchema]` and `originalPost: [subPostSchema]` from my `subPostSchema` worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution: see the comments to my post
general: I can't add the originalPost to my sharedPost which has the originalPost in it -> endless loop. Preventing the loop worked