# Use one Schema for two tasks

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have created Task schema and need to create subtask schema ( which also have same fields like task schema). Can I use the task Schema for the subtask schema? ( only one schema for both work)  If so, please help me out.

```
const Task = mongoose.Schema({
"taskName":String,
"startDate":Date,
"description":String,
"subTask":[{type:String}]
});

const SubTask =  mongoose.Schema({
"subTaskName":String,
"startDate":Date,
"description":String,
});
```

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413864/are-circular-object-references-possible-in-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Schema is just the structure. Any structure that's the same, use the same schema.

If your subtask is same as your task schema, then use the same task schema.

IF your subtask becomes different, then create a new schema for this subtask, and use that new schema.

Answer (score 0):

```
const Task = mongoose.Schema({
  "taskName": String,
  "startDate": Date,
  "description": String,
  "subTask":[{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'SubTask'
  }]
});

const SubTask =  mongoose.Schema({
  "subTaskName": String,
  "startDate": Date,
  "description": String,
  createdBy : {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Task'
  }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.